# Why do src rpms differ

Tags: mocking, fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I have been building rpms using mock.  It is a 2 step process like so.

```
mkdir buildsrpm
mock buildsrpm --spec myprogram-1.spec --sources myprogram-1.tar.gz --resultdir buildsrpm
mkdir rebuild
mock rebuild buildsrpm/myprogram-1.src.rpm --resultdir rebuild
```

The first step is building a source rpm.  The second step is building an rpm.

In the process I use, I create directories to store results.

I have noticed when I run
`diff -qrs buildsrpm/myprogram-1.src.rpm rebuild/myprogram-1.src.rpm` the result is they are different.

So my questions are:

1. Why does `mock rebuild` generate a source rpm?  Obviously I do not need one as I provided a source rpm as the input for the rebuild.
2. Why are they different?
3. If I am creating a repository is one better than the other?

Comment: What does `diff` actually report as being different between the SRPMs? Anything meaningful or just timestamps/etc.? Compare the outputs from `rpm -qp --dump` on both of them?

Comment: I can't verify right now, but I know regular RPMs have timestamp info of when they were built; do SRPMs as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it in different chroot. E.g:

```
mock -r fedora-23-x86_64  foo-1.0.16-1.fc22.src.rpm
```

And you will notice that it will create (beside binary package) `foo-1.0.16-1.fc23.src.rpm`. See the difference in disttag.

The resulting SRPM is build inside of the chroot using `rpmbuild` command from that chroot. This may or may not result in difference (try `rpm -qpi` on those src.rpm). Between Fedora 22 and 23 there will be likely no difference but 'Build Date' (and therefore they are binary different always). But Epel-5 and Fedora-23 will have even differences in used checksum (MD5 vs. SHA).

And if you use [Mock's sign plugin](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock/Plugin/Sign?rd=Subprojects/Mock/Plugin/Sign) then the resulting SRPM can be even signed.

To sum it up - you should rather use the rebuilt SRPM to stay on safe side. However the original SRPM will usually work as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for explaining it.